# Thread-safe lockless memory pool: free function does not behave correctly in multi-thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety, interlocked

I have a simple implementation of a thread-safe allocator of same-sized buffers.
Inside, the implementation is a very simple interlocked singly-linked list, that utilizes the unused space in unallocated buffers to maintain a singly-linked list.

Also wrote some tests, that test the code in single-threaded mode - everything seems to be ok.
Managed to isolate the problem to the *Free* function, but I just can't seem to find it.

I have to mention, that I ran some tests with the exact same code using [Microsoft's Interlocked Singly Linked Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/interlocked-singly-linked-lists), and obviously it works, but I still want to find out what is the problem with my implementation.
Even tried disassembling the code and applying similar intrinsics, but it did not help (also to note, that I don't need to keep track of number of list entries, so that is why I don't need interlock function to exchange double register-size elements like [InterlockedCompareExchange128](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange128) for x64)

Here is the allocator's code:

```
#ifndef _POOLNOLOCK_HPP_
#define _POOLNOLOCK_HPP_

#include <windows.h>

template<size_t TSizeOfElem>
class PoolNoLock {
public:
    PoolNoLock(size_t N) :
        n(N),
        arr(new ELEMENT[n])
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; (n - 1) > i; ++i)
        {
            arr[i].next = &arr[i + 1];
        }
        arr[n - 1].next = nullptr;

        for (size_t i = 0; n > i; ++i)
        {
            arr[i].allocated = false;
        }
    }

    ~PoolNoLock() { delete[] arr; }

    void *Alloc()
    {
        ELEMENT *allocBuff;

        do
        {
            allocBuff = ptrFree;
            if (!allocBuff)
            {
                return nullptr;
            }
        } while (allocBuff != InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(
            reinterpret_cast<void *volatile *>(&ptrFree),
            allocBuff->next,
            allocBuff
        ));

        if (allocBuff->allocated)
        {
            __debugbreak(); //will break here
        }

        allocBuff->allocated = true;

        return &allocBuff->buff;
    }

    void Free(void *Address)
    {
        ELEMENT *const freeBuff = reinterpret_cast<ELEMENT *>(Address);

        if (!freeBuff->allocated)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }

        freeBuff->allocated = false;

        ELEMENT *cmpFree = ptrFree;
        do
        {
            freeBuff->next = cmpFree;

            ELEMENT *const xchgFree =
                reinterpret_cast<ELEMENT *>(InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(
                    reinterpret_cast<void *volatile *>(&ptrFree),
                    freeBuff,
                    cmpFree
                ));

            if (xchgFree == cmpFree)
            {
                break;
            }

            cmpFree = xchgFree;
        } while (true);
    }

private:
    typedef struct _ELEMENT {
        union {
            _ELEMENT *next;
            unsigned char buff[TSizeOfElem];
        };
        bool allocated; //debug info
    }ELEMENT;

    const size_t n;
    ELEMENT *const arr; //array of list elements

    ELEMENT *volatile ptrFree = &arr[0]; //head of "singly" linked list
};

#endif // _POOLNOLOCK_HPP_
```

And this is the code I use to stress-test the class:

1. 64 is the maximum number of objects, that [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) can wait for
2. the wait in the thread is needed to help achieve a scenario, where as much thread as possible is accessing the resource
3. the number of thread spawned is exactly equal to the number of elements in the allocator, this is the reason why the alloc-only test works

```
#include "PoolNoLock.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

static constexpr size_t N_THREAD = 64;
static constexpr size_t N_TEST_RUN = 4;
static constexpr size_t N_ALLOC_FREE = 1024;

struct ThreadParam {
    PoolNoLock<sizeof(size_t)> *allocator;
    const HANDLE &hStartEvent;
    void *addressAlloc = nullptr;

    ThreadParam(PoolNoLock<sizeof(size_t)> *Allocator, const HANDLE &StartEvent) :
        allocator(Allocator),
        hStartEvent(StartEvent)
    {};
};

template<bool TAllocOnly>
class Test {
public:
    ~Test()
    {
        CloseHandle(hStartEvent);
    }

    bool RunSingle(PoolNoLock<sizeof(size_t)> *Allocator)
    {
        std::vector<ThreadParam> params(N_THREAD, ThreadParam(Allocator, hStartEvent));

        if (TRUE != ResetEvent(hStartEvent))
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; N_THREAD != i; ++i)
        {
            handles[i] = CreateThread(nullptr,
                0,
                reinterpret_cast<PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(threadProc),
                &params[i],
                CREATE_SUSPENDED,
                &tids[i]);
            if (!handles[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (HANDLE handle : handles)
        {
            if (1 != ResumeThread(handle))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (TRUE != SetEvent(hStartEvent))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ((WAIT_OBJECT_0 + N_THREAD - 1) < WaitForMultipleObjects(N_THREAD, handles, TRUE, INFINITE))
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; N_THREAD != i; ++i)
        {
            if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(handles[i], 0))
            {
                return false;
            }

            DWORD exitCode;
            if (TRUE != GetExitCodeThread(handles[i], &exitCode))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (0 != exitCode)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (TRUE != CloseHandle(handles[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (TAllocOnly)
        {
            std::map<void *, DWORD> threadAllocations;

            for (size_t i = 0; N_THREAD != i; ++i)
            {
                if (!params[i].addressAlloc)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (threadAllocations.end() == threadAllocations.find(params[i].addressAlloc))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                std::pair<std::map<void *, DWORD>::iterator, bool> res =
                    threadAllocations.insert(std::make_pair(params[i].addressAlloc, tids[i]));

                if (!res.second)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                Allocator->Free(params[i].addressAlloc);
            }

            if (N_THREAD != threadAllocations.size())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool RunMultiple()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; N_TEST_RUN != i; ++i)
        {
            PoolNoLock<sizeof(size_t)> allocator(N_THREAD);
            RunSingle(&allocator);
        }

        return true;
    }

private:
    const HANDLE hStartEvent = CreateEventW(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr);

    HANDLE handles[N_THREAD] = { nullptr };
    DWORD tids[N_THREAD] = { 0 };

    static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProcAllocOnly(_In_ ThreadParam *Param)
    {
        if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(Param->hStartEvent, INFINITE))
        {
            return 2;
        }

        Param->addressAlloc = Param->allocator->Alloc();
        if (!Param->addressAlloc)
        {
            return 3;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProcAllocFree(_In_ ThreadParam *Param)
    {
        if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(Param->hStartEvent, INFINITE))
        {
            return 2;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; N_ALLOC_FREE != i; ++i)
        {
            void *ptrTest = Param->allocator->Alloc();
            if (!ptrTest)
            {
                return 3;
            }

            Param->allocator->Free(ptrTest);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    const LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE threadProc =
        TAllocOnly
        ? reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(ThreadProcAllocOnly)
        : reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(ThreadProcAllocFree);
};

int main()
{
    Test<true> testAllocOnly0;
    Test<false> TestAllocFree0;

    if (!testAllocOnly0.RunMultiple()) //this test will succeed
    {
        std::cout << "Test failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Alloc-ONLY tests succeeded" << std::endl;

    if (!TestAllocFree0.RunMultiple()) //this test will fail
    {
        std::cout << "Test failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Alloc/free tests succeeded" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "All tests succeeded" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should add Win-API or similar tag, since the functions you are using are Windows API specific.  If someone were to read your title, what would be expected would be C++ standard threading functions.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior.  `arr[i].next = &arr[i + 1];` is setting one field of the union and then `arr[i].data.allocated = false;` sets the other member of the union as active and sets it's value.  The value that `next` used to have is now gone.

Comment: your problem in `Alloc`. this is well known. assume you have chain `F - a - b - c` and you want pop `a` and assign `F` to `b`. but before you do this another threads first pop `a`: `F - b - c` then pop `b`: `F - c` and push `a`: `F - a - c`. because `F` pointed to `a` again the CAS will be ok and you make chain `F - b - *trash*` because `b` really in use now.

Comment: fixed the internal structure, so _allocated_ does not overwrite _next_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your error in `Alloc()` routine. more exactly in line

```
InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(
            reinterpret_cast<void *volatile *>(&ptrFree),
            allocBuff->next, // <-- !!!
            allocBuff)
```

here 2 operations : first cpu read `allocBuff->next` from `allocBuff` pointer and then try *CAS* on `ptrFree` but this 2 operations not atomic and can be break between it . at time when you try use `allocBuff->next` - the `allocBuff` can be already alocated by another thread and `next` overwriten to trash (not valid pointer for instance).

so let exist 2 threads: T#1 and T#2

- T#1 read `allocBuff` from `ptrFree`
- T#2 read `allocBuff` from `ptrFree`
- T#2 return `allocBuff` to user
- T#2 overwrite context of `allocBuff->next` to user data, let to -1.
- T#1 read `next = allocBuff->next` and got some user data ( -1 )
- T#2 free/push `allocBuff` back to `ptrFree`
- T#1 ok in CAS because `ptrFree` point again to `allocBuff`. `ptrFree` point
  to -1 now
- T#2 read -1 from `ptrFree`
- T#2 try read from -1
- crash

here even only single element (a) in stack and 2 threads enough for demo. let the same example:
where head (F) and element (a) in stack. initial state:
F -> a -> 0

- T#1 read **a** from **F**
- T#2 read **a** from **F**
- T#2 read **0** from **a**
- T#2 write **0** to **F** and return a to user : **F -> 0**
- T#2 write **-1** to **a**: **a = -1;**
- T#1 read **-1** from **a**
- T#2 free **a**: **F -> a -> 0**
- T#1 write **-1** to **F** and return **a** to user : **F -> -1**
- T#2 read **-1** from **F**
- T#2 try read from **-1**

possible and another race here

**F - a - b - c**

and you want pop **a** and assign **F** to **b**. but before you do this another threads first pop **a**, so now

**F - b - c**

then pop **b**:

**F - c**

and push/free **a**:

**F - a - c.**

because **F** pointed to **a** again the CAS will be ok and you make chain

**F - b - trash**

because **b** really in use now.

---

in any case your implementation very far from the best. you not need templates here, the `TSizeOfElem` and `n` need know only at init procedure and no more need. for stress test need not many threads, but delays in critical points

```
void NotifyAllocated(PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY allocBuff)
{
    allocBuff->Next = (PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; // allocated = true;
    
    WCHAR sz[16], txt[64];
    swprintf_s(sz, _countof(sz), L"%x", GetCurrentThreadId());
    swprintf_s(txt, _countof(txt), L"alocated = %p", allocBuff);
    
    MessageBoxW(0, txt, sz, MB_ICONINFORMATION); // simulate delay !
}

void NotifyCheck(PVOID buf, PCWSTR fmt)
{
    WCHAR sz[16], txt[64];
    swprintf_s(sz, _countof(sz), L"%x", GetCurrentThreadId());
    swprintf_s(txt, _countof(txt), fmt, buf);
    MessageBoxW(0, txt, sz, MB_ICONWARNING); // simulate delay !
}

class PoolNoLock 
{
    PVOID _arr = 0;                     //array of list elements
    PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY _ptrFree = 0;    //head of "singly" linked list

public:
    bool Init(size_t N, size_t SizeOfElem)
    {
        if (N)
        {
            if (SizeOfElem < sizeof(SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY))
            {
                SizeOfElem = sizeof(SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY);
            }

            union {
                PUCHAR buf;
                PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY Next;
            };

            if (buf = new UCHAR[N * SizeOfElem])
            {
                _arr = buf;

                PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY ptrFree = 0;

                do 
                {
                    Next->Next = ptrFree;
                    ptrFree = Next;
                } while (buf += SizeOfElem, --N);

                _ptrFree = ptrFree;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    ~PoolNoLock() 
    { 
        if (PVOID buf = _arr)
        {
            delete[] buf; 
        }
    }

    void *Alloc()
    {
        PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY allocBuff, ptrFree = _ptrFree;

        for (;;)
        {
            allocBuff = ptrFree;

            if (!allocBuff)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            NotifyCheck(allocBuff, L"try: %p");

            // access allocBuff->Next !!
            PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY Next = allocBuff->Next;

            NotifyCheck(Next, L"next: %p");

            ptrFree = (PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY)InterlockedCompareExchangePointer((void**)&_ptrFree, Next, allocBuff);
            //ptrFree = (PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY)InterlockedCompareExchangePointer((void**)&_ptrFree, allocBuff->Next, allocBuff);

            if (ptrFree == allocBuff)
            {
                NotifyAllocated(allocBuff);
                return allocBuff;
            }
        }
    }

    void Free(void *Address)
    {
        PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY ptrFree = _ptrFree, newFree;

        for ( ; ; ptrFree = newFree)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY>(Address)->Next = ptrFree;

            newFree = (PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY)InterlockedCompareExchangePointer((void**)&_ptrFree, Address, ptrFree);

            if (newFree == ptrFree)
            {
                return ;
            }
        }
    }
};

ULONG ThreadTest(PoolNoLock* p)
{
    ULONG n = 2;
    do 
    {
        WCHAR sz[16], txt[32];
        swprintf_s(sz, _countof(sz), L"%x", GetCurrentThreadId());
        swprintf_s(txt, _countof(txt), L"loop %x", n);
        MessageBoxW(0, txt, sz, MB_OK);
        if (void* buf = p->Alloc())
        {
            p->Free(buf);
        }
    } while (--n);

    return 0;
}

void DemoTest()
{
    PoolNoLock p;
    if (p.Init(1, sizeof(PVOID)))
    {
        ULONG n = 2;
        do 
        {
            CloseHandle(CreateThread(0, 0, (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadTest, &p, 0, 0));
        } while (--n);
    }

    MessageBoxW(0, 0, L"Wait", MB_OK);
}
```

this is same as your code, only optimized. bug the same - at

```
ptrFree = (PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY)InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(
        (void**)&_ptrFree, allocBuff->Next, allocBuff);
```

for test and better understand - better write as

```
PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY Next = allocBuff->Next;

// delay !!

ptrFree = (PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY)InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(
    (void**)&_ptrFree, Next, allocBuff);
```

---

for solve this problem `SLIST_HEADER` used - this is by fact combination of pointer to stack top + operation count. correct implementation can be next (if not direct use `SLIST_HEADER` and api for it)

```
class PoolNoLock 
{
    PVOID _arr = 0;                     //array of list elements

    struct U  
    {
        PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY ptr; //head of "singly" linked list
        ULONG_PTR allocCount;

        void operator = (U& v)
        {
            ptr = v.ptr;
            allocCount = v.allocCount;
        }

        U(U* v)
        {
            ptr = v->ptr->Next;
            allocCount = v->allocCount + 1;
        }

        U(PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY ptr, ULONG_PTR allocCount) : ptr(ptr), allocCount(allocCount)
        {
        }

        U() : ptr(0), allocCount(0)
        {
        }

    } u;

    //++ debug
    LONG _allocMiss = 0;
    LONG _freeMiss = 0;
    //-- debug

public:
    bool Init(size_t N, size_t SizeOfElem)
    {
        if (N)
        {
            if (SizeOfElem < sizeof(SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY))
            {
                SizeOfElem = sizeof(SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY);
            }

            union {
                PUCHAR buf;
                PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY Next;
            };

            if (buf = new UCHAR[N * SizeOfElem])
            {
                _arr = buf;

                PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY ptrFree = 0;

                do 
                {
                    Next->Next = ptrFree;
                    ptrFree = Next;
                } while (buf += SizeOfElem, --N);

                u.ptr = ptrFree;
                u.allocCount = 0;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    ~PoolNoLock() 
    { 
        if (PVOID buf = _arr)
        {
            delete[] buf; 
        }
    }

    void *Alloc()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            U allocBuff = u;

            if (!allocBuff.ptr)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            U Next(&allocBuff);

            if (InterlockedCompareExchange128((LONG64*)&u, Next.allocCount, (LONG64)Next.ptr, (LONG64*)&allocBuff))
            {
                // for debug only
                allocBuff.ptr->Next = (PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

                return allocBuff.ptr;
            } 

            // for debug only
            InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_allocMiss);
        }
    }

    void Free(void *Address)
    {
        for ( ; ; )
        {
            U ptrFree = u;
            U a(reinterpret_cast<PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY>(Address), ptrFree.allocCount);
            
            reinterpret_cast<PSINGLE_LIST_ENTRY>(Address)->Next = ptrFree.ptr;

            if (InterlockedCompareExchange128((LONG64*)&u, a.allocCount, (LONG64)a.ptr, (LONG64*)&ptrFree))
            {
                return ;
            }

            // for debug only
            InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_freeMiss);
        }
    }
};

ULONG ThreadTest(PoolNoLock* p)
{
    ULONG n = 0x10000;
    do 
    {
        if (void* buf = p->Alloc())
        {
            p->Free(buf);
        }
    } while (--n);

    return 0;
}

void DemoTest()
{
    PoolNoLock p;
    if (p.Init(16, sizeof(PVOID)))
    {
        ULONG n = 8;
        do 
        {
            CloseHandle(CreateThread(0, 0, (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadTest, &p, 0, 0));
        } while (--n);
    }

    MessageBoxW(0, 0, L"Wait", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: thanks. in the meantime i looked up what you wrote in the comment and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863101/trying-to-write-a-lock-free-singly-linked-list-trouble-with-the-removal and this: http://15418.courses.cs.cmu.edu/spring2013/article/46, which explain pretty well the problem

Comment: @user2281752 - yes, this is *The ABA Problem* in your list.

Comment: also [InterlockedCompareExchange128](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange128) may not be available on rather old processors (they should be really rare by now).

Comment: theoretically there should be another solution where I store an _isAllocated_ element in each node, use interlock to "mark" it as being in the process of allocation, then use another interlock to do the actual swapping, all the while the code bein in a double loop, very **similar** to [RtlInterlockedPopEntrySList](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d5/d52/slist_8c.html#abe7ed89a36a3dd82ec9d3174a2b54faf) from ReactOS.

Comment: @user2281752 -  InterlockedCompareExchange128 need for 64bit system . for 32bit need - 64 bit. 2 pointers size ( 2*64 or 2*32) need swap at once. `RtlInterlockedPopEntrySList` yes this api and need use actually with `SLIST_HEADER` i only paste here internal implementation for demo. if you look to Rtl function code, yoi can view `lock cmpxchg16b` here

Comment: I linked the wrong article, here it is: [_InterlockedCompareExchange128](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/interlockedcompareexchange128?view=msvc-170)

`The _InterlockedCompareExchange128 intrinsic generates the cmpxchg16b instruction (with the lock prefix) to perform a 128-bit locked compare and exchange. Early versions of AMD 64-bit hardware don't support this instruction. To check for hardware support for the cmpxchg16b instruction, call the __cpuid intrinsic with InfoType=0x00000001 (standard function 1). Bit 13 of CPUInfo[2] (ECX) is 1 if the instruction is supported.`